# NSIS nsDialogPage are not shown anymore because of temp files access issue?

Tags: nsis, nsdialogs

Few hours ago, my deploying project was correctly running. 
But suddenly, after I add a second `nsDialogPage` on my project, its not working anymore. 
Even the old saved code with only one `nsDialogPage`.

This is part of my code.

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh  
!include StrRep.nsh
!include ReplaceInFile.nsh  
!include FileFunc.nsh       
!include TextFunc.nsh   
!insertmacro GetTime   
!include ZipDLL.nsh 

; The name of the installer
Name "Packaging setup"

; The file to write
OutFile "Packaging setup v1.2.3.exe"

XPStyle on

Var Dialog
Var Label
Var UserText

; The default installation directory
InstallDir "C:\temp\setup"

; Request application privileges for Windows Vista
RequestExecutionLevel admin

; Pages

Page components
Page directory
;Page custom nsDialogsPage nsDialogsPageLeave
Page instfiles
Page custom nsDialogsPage nsDialogsPageLeave

UninstPage uninstConfirm
UninstPage instfiles

Section "Copy files"

; Set output path to the installation directory.
SetOutPath $INSTDIR

; Copy lot of files
File "D:\Temp\Sources\parametrage.txt"
SectionEnd

Function nsDialogsPage
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $Dialog

${If} $Dialog == error
    MessageBox MB_OK "Oops something crashed"
    Abort
${EndIf}

;UserName
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 18% 10u "UserName : "
Pop $Label
${ConfigRead} "$INSTDIR\parametrage.txt" "@DERBY_USER@ = " $UserText
${NSD_CreateTExt} 50u 0 50% 12u $UserText
Pop $UserText

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function nsDialogsPageLeave
!macro _ReplaceInFile2 SOURCE_FILE SEARCH_TEXT REPLACEMENT
    Push "${SOURCE_FILE}"
    Push "${SEARCH_TEXT}"
    Push "${REPLACEMENT}"
    Call RIF
!macroend

;${ConfigRead} "$INSTDIR\PARAMETRAGE.txt" "@DERBY_USER@ = " $0
${NSD_GetText} $UserText $0
!insertmacro _ReplaceInFile2 "$INSTDIR\$Version\conf\database.properties" "@DERBY_USER@" $0

FunctionEnd
```

This code was working perfectely until a moment. I dont know what happens.

Currently, the setup stopped after the copy of the files, and does not display the nsDialog form. 
To notice :

- If I comment the files copy page, the `nsDialog` Pages appears normally
- If I make the `nsDialog` first, then the copy page, then the `nsDialog` again (just to test, it is useless on my application), the first `nsDialog` form appears, but not the second one.

I thought it was coming from the `${NSD_CreateTExt}` so I tried the same action with only label (not text) and the result is the same.

The copy of my files are correctly completed (it is logged).

And it was working, before I don't know what.

I restarted my machine, without any result.

On a other project similarly the same, kind of a ".tmp file issue " related to the `nsDialog` is displayed on the setup form. 
A clue ?

Any advice would be welcome. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen McAfee cause this with the maximum security settings. One of their protections is against executing files from the temporary directory.

It doesn't fit exactly with your issue as sometimes it does work for you, but it's worth a shot trying it out.

Comment: Good idea. But the workstation with the code is not connected to the Internet (no update), and even if it is McAfee, how explain that it has worked ?

Comment: By latest I just mean the one of the last versions, not necessarily the latest update. Give it a shot and disable AV. Should be simple enough to verify.